# GO SMS conversation grouping by number, not contact

Tags: go-sms

I installed GO SMS pro today and it looks good, but there is one thing that is a deal breaker for me.

Some of the people I know use different numbers (grouped under one contact) to text me, however when I open GO SMS conversations aren't grouped by contact, but instead it looks like they are grouped by number (3 separate conversation threads for one contact).

Is there any way to group them by contact? This is how the default messaging app works (conversations grouped by contact, reply goes to last number used from the conversation).